# Which pairs of countries are connected by land but can't be connected by car?

Tags: international-travel, driving, borders, where-on-earth

Can't be connected by car = a regular individual can't drive a regular vehicle between the two countries,  including via another country.

I'm not interested in the case where driving is made impossible because of some military conflicts, e.g  with North Korea.

I'm aware of ([Panama, Colombia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap)). Is there any other such pair of countries?

Comment: Almost a match, Brazil-France border has only been open to cars for 5 years on the [Oyapock River Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyapock_River_Bridge)

Comment: @Vince I believe you could have gone through Suriname and Guyana.

Comment: I doubt there are many other examples. It would nearly require the two countries to have a coast-to-coast border (not that many) without any crossings, otherwise via 3rd countries there's going to be a more or les convoluted way. Just in case, do crossings using a ferry across a river count?

Comment: Would India and China count? See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63632/why-don-t-china-and-india-open-at-least-one-border-crossing

Comment: That's an interesting case, but I guess you could still drive around. There are a couple of interesting land borders that cannot be crossed but one can still take a detour to connect the two countries

Comment: From the Panama / Colombia example, I guess the question could be "countries with a land border but no public accessible road crossing the border, and no other land route either".

Comment: @WeatherVane that's right

Comment: I was all set to throw out Indonesia/Papua New Guinea but it does appear that there's a land border crossing on the northern coast near Jayapura.

Comment: I guess there might be some military bases that are actual enclaves and are not accessible by car.

Comment: @Vince:  [Guantanamo Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guantanamo_Bay_Naval_Base) springs to mind.  But I think the land is nominally leased by the United States and is still *de jure* Cuban.

Comment: I wanted to suggest Timor (Indonesia) and East Timor, but there seem to be exactly 4 border roads: at the north and south coasts, and 2 into the northern ET enclave (didn't know it had one). The Google camera van hasn't been in ET, only around the Indonesia territory, and it didn't reach two of the borders, where the cartography style perhaps suggests poor (unsurfaced?) roads. But I can see on Google Earth that all four are metalled, so that's out.

Comment: @jcaron good point, let's not count ferry crossings as car crossing (otherwise it looks like we'll have only Antarctic and microstates, and I'm guessing we could find ferry connecting some rather distant countries)

Comment: Niger, Chad and Libya have no *direct* road crossings.

Comment: If we can quibble over "connected by land", I nominate the US and Russia, which at some times of the year are connected by a natural ice bridge between the [Diomede Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diomede_Islands).  You can't drive that route because it's ice, and there's no other land route between them.  Does it count?  Ice is like land in that it's a solid.

Comment: I also wondered about France and the UK, connected "by land" at the crossing point of the Channel Tunnel.  It may be *under* the water, but you would be standing on dry land if you were to walk across it.  Again, you can't drive through the tunnel (rail only) and the two countries have no other land route between them that I know of. ... Oh no, wait, you can drive from France to Gibraltar, so maybe that counts as "connected by car".

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, that's interesting, we could add these cases as answers as I can't think of any similar cases with tunnel/ice. I couldn't find an ice link between Canada and Greenland.

Comment: @NateEldredge Gibraltar is not part of the UK; it is a dependency.

Comment: Does two wheels count as "driving"?  It's possible to go through the Darien on a motorcycle.  Though definitely NOT recommended.  (Or so it seems from reading—I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no roads connecting **Suriname** to any of its neighbors (France, Guyana, or Brazil), though there are ferry connections over the rivers to Guyana and France.

(Wikivoyage says that there's a road between Suriname and Guyana, but it's wrong: [satellite imagery clearly shows](https://goo.gl/maps/so6zBhqKWFtsYJteA) a hole in the road, and [travelers' reports](https://www.veryhungrynomads.com/how-to-get-from-georgetown-to-paramaribo/) clearly state that a transfer to and from the ferry is required.

Comment: Yep, I crossed that border 3 years ago and there was no road for sure, ferry was the only option

Comment: A [bridge is apparently in the works](https://dpi.gov.gy/new-request-for-proposals-to-be-advertised-for-guyana-suriname-bridge/) at the same location, but it's still early days.  Check back in 5–10 years.

Comment: I would say that a road ferry is still a road: You can connect to a car by spending half an hour and never leaving it.

Answer (score 20):

The **Italian Republic** and the **Vatican City State**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City) states

> The **Vatican City State**, also known simply as the **Vatican**, became independent from Italy with the Lateran Treaty (1929), and it is a distinct territory under "full ownership, exclusive dominion, and sovereign authority and jurisdiction" of the Holy See, itself a sovereign entity of international law.

The page [Travel to Vatican City](https://everything-everywhere.com/travel-vatican-city/) states

> **Driving**: In Vatican City, they drive on the right side of the road, but it is highly unlikely that you will ever drive inside the Vatican. The only way the public can drive in the Vatican is if you’re there on official business and enter a via parking lot near St. Ann’s.

So it qualifies under OP's conditions

- a regular individual can't drive a regular vehicle between the two countries
- there is no ongoing military conflict preventing it

Answer (score 11):

**Canada** and **Denmark** have recently announced that [they will divide Hans Island between them.](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/canada-denmark-reach-hans-island-deal-after-50-year-dispute-1.6487325)  Hans Island is a small uninhabited island in the middle of the Nares Strait between Greenland and Ellesmere Island;  before this treaty, both countries had claimed ownership of the island.

This treaty, once ratified, will create a land border between the two countries that cannot be driven across;  the island is uninhabited and there are no bridges leading to it.

Answer (score 7):

Various Antarctic territorial claims provide "land borders" that cannot be crossed due to the lack of roads, including:

- Australia & New Zealand (160°E)
- Australia & France (142°2′E and 136°11′E)
- Australia & Norway (44°38′E)
- Norway & United Kingdom (20°E)

None of these countries share a land border anywhere else in the world, of course.  **EDIT:**  *As was pointed out by Nate Eldridge in the comments, it is possible to drive from Norway to Gibraltar, which is also a British Overseas Territory;  so the last of these does not qualify.*

For the purposes of this question, it is probably best to draw a discreet veil over the conflicts between the claims of Chile, Argentina, and the UK, as they make the concept of a "border" ill-defined.  The Chile-Argentina border on the South American continent is relatively easy to cross anyhow.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can't drive from Norway to the UK?

Comment: There is no car traffic in the Channel tunnel, cars go on a train.

Comment: @Doc:  Depends if you count a ferry or the Chunnel as "driving".  But if you count ferries as driving then the Panama/Colombia link might not count either.

Comment: From the north you can drive as far as Yaviza in Panama, and from the south as far as Turbo in Colombia. How far can you get towards each of these Antarctica borders, and from where, in "a regular vehicle"?

Comment: @WeatherVane:  Presumably you can't get anywhere near them, but the OP didn't specify that you needed to. [<technicallycorrect.gif>](https://tenor.com/view/correct-technically-correct-technically-futurama-best-gif-4999851)

Comment: Actually, I think you can drive from Norway to the UK, without ferries or Chunnel: https://goo.gl/maps/4pUZXoGzh1mhamZH6.  Gibraltar is a British Overseas Territory just like the British Antarctic territory is, so if you count one you've got to count the other.  :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge:  Hoist by my own petard!

Answer (score 5):

Singapore and Malaysia are connected by a causeway and a bridge, with the Causeway in regular times being the world's busiest border crossing by some measures.

However, due to COVID-19, for much of 2020-2022 **both were completely closed to private passenger vehicles**: the only way to cross was by designated bus services.  Both links reopened on April 1, 2022.

Comment: Isn't the bridge technically closed because of the war against COVID, breaking OPs rules? :)

Comment: @JonathanReez that's not a "military conflict".

Comment: @WeatherVane You missed the joke re: "war" on COVID...

Comment: It is open now.

Comment: Crossed that border myself 11 days ago. But this case should be included in an expanded version of the "for political reasons" caveat. Heaps of land borders were and a good few still are closed to normal motorists due to covid. Malaysia/Thailand land border was still closed to normal traffic when I checked a few days ago. You have to fly to an island and stay there for a week or two before you're allowed into the Thai mainland.

Comment: @hippietrail That hasn't been the case for quite some time, Malaysia reopened the main borderi crossings to Thailand for all travellers on May 5th: https://thethaiger.com/news/regional/malaysia-en/3-malaysia-thailand-border-crossings-reopening

Comment: @lambshaanxy: I was talking about going from Malaysia to Thailand. Sorry I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to stretch the definition of "connected by land": [the UK and France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France%E2%80%93UK_border) are connected by land, namely the [Channel Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_Tunnel).

You can't drive through it as it consists of two train tunnels plus a pedestrian service tunnel - though you can take your car [on a train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurotunnel_Shuttle).